# "Normal" regexps in vim

Tags: regex, vim

How to use "usual" regexps in vim's search `/`? I mean something like `[0-9]+\d+\S*`, and not the vim syntax? I find vim's syntax annoying and constantly have to check how to express something in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you encounter most possibly is because of magic. See `:help /magic` inside of ViM. What you can do is add `\v` as the first member of your pattern. Example:

```
/\v[0-9]+\d+\S*
```

Explanation from the manual:

```
Use of "\v" means that in the pattern after it all ASCII characters except
'0'-'9', 'a'-'z', 'A'-'Z' and '_' have a special meaning.  "very magic"
```

You can also set the `magic` option (see `:help magic`).

Comment: Note that this still doesn't give you Perl-compatible regexps; you still have to use `\<` / `\>` instead of `\b`. But you get used to it soon...

Comment: Here is additional note: if you strictly follow documentation then you must escape spaces, colons, semicolons, hash signs and, probably, something other despite the fact that they *currently* do nothing special.

Comment: +1 for this sentence alone: The problem you encounter most possibly is because of magic.